# Python(3.6) Spyder :on running a file containing .npy extension for data set it shows Import Error :Cannot import name '_mklinit'

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

[st.py the main program for execution](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NKWJY1g8lcm4u8ty8TiCvTfP8EvEwJrs) [_distributor_init.py](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_ttPwjDJFTt0JnZXqLqMeBc_BzfW4vX4)
[*init*.py](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Tk5Zz8ixG9EcUNHs8q4B7x9vOdbwCo5l)   Python(3.6) Spyder: on running a file containing .npy extension for data set it shows

Import Error: Cannot import name '_mklinit'`:
File "C:\Users\AB\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\np_utils.py", line 6, in

import numpy as np
      File "C:\Users\AB\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\Lib\site-packages\numpy__init__.py", line 140, in

```
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\AB\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\Lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module>

    from . import _mklinit
ImportError: cannot import name '_mklinit'
```

Comment: Please show the code you have used. With only the error message we cannot help much.

Answer (score 0):

uninstall anaconda.
Delete the  Anaconda folder from C/Users/AB/Anaconda.
Again install anaconda .
install numpy using the following 
pip install numpy

Answer (score 0):

A bit extreme to uninstall Anaconda.  Had much the same problem with one of my own package distributions. Could not import scipy.special.  Same error.

Assuming you have Python-3.6, try these installs first:

```
conda install -c intel mkl

conda install mkl-include
```

This should straighten out 'C:\Users\*you*\Anaconda3\DLLs' such that your code will work in Spyder.

If you have another Python environment installed be careful that its DLL folder is also fixed or it will work in Spyder but the same code will fail in Idle.